# boost::thread::interrupt - Can a parent thread interrupt the child thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost, boost-thread

I know that the parent thread can call `interrupt()` on child thread's object. The child thread on execution of a specified interruption point will raise an exception which will need to be caught by the interrupted thread.

My problem is that my child thread has hanged and hence it can not execute the code such as `boost::this_thread::interruption_point()`.

In parent thread, I tried calling join on child thread object soon after I detect the child thread is hanged. But `thread_interrupted` is not raised.

Is there any way to interrupt a child/worker thread that has hanged?

Comment: There is no parent/child relationship for threads. One thread can all `interrupt()` on another.

Comment: thanks Slava. I was merely trying to highlight delegate/worker thread relationship. Boost doc says: "When the interrupted thread next executes one of the specified interruption points (or if it is currently blocked whilst executing one) with interruption enabled, then a boost::thread_interrupted exception will be thrown in the interrupted thread." I was wondering if the interruption point can be executed by delegate thread: Like, worker.interrupt() and somewhere later worker.join() ?